# Why do I need an intermediate swap function for the compiler to be able to deduce the type?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class T>
void swap(T &t1, T &t2)
{
    T tmp = t1;
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = tmp;
}

template <class Bi>
void reverse(Bi begin, Bi end)
{
    while (begin != end) {
        --end;

        if (begin != end) {
            ::swap(*begin++, *end);
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the above work?

```
template <class Bi, class T>
void reverse2(Bi begin, Bi end)
{
    while (begin != end) {
        --end;

        if (begin != end) {
            T tmp = *begin;
            *begin++ = *end;
            *end = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

While this doesn't?

For the first example to work, the compiler has to be able to deduce the argument types of the swap function at compile time. (I.e. it has to be able to determine the types of `*begin++` and `*end`.) If this is possible, why can't the compiler deduce the type of the value returned by `*begin` in the second example and choose `T` accordingly?

Comment: With C++11 you might have some luck with `auto tmp = *begin;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler deduces the argument types from the function **signature**, not the function **body**.

As `T` is not used in the function signature at all (`void reverse2(Bi begin, Bi end)`), the compiler can not deduce the type. However, in the case of `swap` it can deduce the type, because it was deduced in the function signature.